# Change default dist folder with setuptools

Tags: python, directory, packaging, setuptools

I'm using `setuptools` 0.6 to package my code. By default when I type `python setup.py sdist`, the tool creates a folder dist directly in the same folder of my script. What I can do to change this default folder?
Edit: Another question is, if my setup script and my package folder are not in the same folder, what can I do to specify the exact path of the package?
Thanks

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Use the `--dist-dir=[differentdir]` option. From `python setup.py sdist --help`:

> ```
>   --dist-dir (-d)   directory to put the source distribution archive(s) in
>                     [default: dist]
> ```

You can specify the top-level package directory with the `package_dir` keyword argument to `setup()`:

```
package_dir = {'': 'src'},
```

I can recommend the [Python Packaging User Guide](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/) for a good tutorial on how to package your python projects.